# p:dataTable ajax page event error in list update

Tags: jsf, primefaces

In Primefaces 5.1 I display student name using dataTable when press link to move to next page see and uncessary student details should press delete button to remove record and update mainPanel.That time I face student list show to first record it fine but pageLinks point 2(**Paginator point second page**).

```
<p:ouputPanel id="mainPanel">
....
    <p:dataTable id="studDataTable" value="#{stud.dataList}" var="stud" rows="3"
rowIndexVar="studeIndex" paginatorTemplate="{Exporters}{CurrentPageReport}
{FirstPageLink}{PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}">
        <p:ajax event="page" listener="#{stud.scrollListener}" update="studDataTable"/>
        <p:column headerText="Name">
            <h:ouputText value=#{stud.name}"/>
        </p:column>
        <p:column>
            <p:commandButton value="Delete" action="#{stud.deleteAction}" 
update=":#{p:component('mainPanel')}">
                <f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{studIndex}" target="#{stud.indexVal}"/>
            </p:commandButton>
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
</p:ouputPanel>
```

List update properly but pagelinks point nextPage not point first page.My doubt with only dataTable first attribute to set first page and any another way focus pagelinks automatically?

Comment: Again there is a syntax error in `<p:dataTable>`. Check [the showcase example](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/paginator.xhtml) but paging should be implemented [lazily](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/lazy.xhtml) - the datasource should be loaded lazily.

Comment: @SVN: Please be careful with posting code that is not a copy-paste of something that is running. **always** create an [mcve]

Comment: and why do you need to explicitly update the dataTable on a page event? The 'data' is already automagically updated.

Comment: @Kukeltje Total 13 records to rows I given rows=10. First page show 10 and second page show 3. I delete record in second Page data updated successfully to show 10 rows But Paginator (PageLinks) focus second page.I need to focus first page